# No space before opening parenthesis on auto format in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to let VS Code format my JS source code it converts

```
for(var key in indexObj)
```

to

```
for (var key in indexObj)
```

How can I prevent VS Code to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install the [beautify plugin for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)
- Create a `.jsbeautifyrc` file. Take [this one](https://gist.github.com/wzup/fc3254562236c1ec3f69) as an example
- Set its `space_before_conditional` value to `false`
- Place the file in your home directory to use it globally or place it in the same folder as the `.js` are located which you want to format
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get your code formatted

Comment: This has solved this problem but generated a new one :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088680/leaving-case-statement-in-one-line-using-beautify-plugin-in-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue with no plugins you can set the configuration on vscode **settings.json**:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": false
}
```

or goes to **File - Preferences - Settings** , looking for **Format On Save** and unchecked it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible by adding this line to settings.json:
`javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": false`

- *false*: no added space: `for(...) {...` and `if(...) {...`
- *true* (default): added space: `for (...) {...` and `if(...) {...`

Instructions for how to open settings.json from within VS Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_how-can-i-reset-my-user-settings