# Leaving case statement in one line using beautify plugin in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

After installing beautify plugin in VS Code pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  results in reformatting a switch case form

```
switch (cmd)
{
    case glob.CmdsClient.GET_CHANGED_ITEMS: cmds.getChangedItems(data, socket); break;
    case glob.CmdsClient.UPDATE_ITEM: cmds.updateItem(data); break;
    default: console.log("Unkonwn CMD #", cmd);
}
```

to

```
switch(cmd) {
    case glob.CmdsClient.GET_CHANGED_ITEMS:
        cmds.getChangedItems(data, socket);
        break;
    case glob.CmdsClient.UPDATE_ITEM:
        cmds.updateItem(data);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Unkonwn CMD #", cmd);
}
```

How can I prevent VS Code to do that?

Comment: There is no option for this in js-beautify.  Please file a feature request on github.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure all keyboard shortcuts from the visual studio options menu. Please check the following links for reference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

Comment: This is not about Visual Studio. It's about about Visual Studio Code and js-beautify. You should delete this answer.